# RenderBody() overlaps with _Layout.cshtml when using jumbotron

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal, render-html

I'm new to ASP.Net, I tried to create a simple login page. Layout page has a jumbotron. But my login controls are overlapped with the jumbotron.

Appreciate your help

**_Layout.cshtml - file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Title</title>
        <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
        <link href="~/css/Main.scss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
        <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="jumbotron">
                  <h2>Welcome to Application</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id ="main" class="col-lg-8">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
   </body> 
</html>
```

**Login.cshtml - Login View**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    if (@ViewBag.LoginErrorMsg != null)
    {
        <div class="form-group has-error">
            @ViewBag.LoginErrorMsg
        </div>
    }

    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.email, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.email)
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is the result I get [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBTvI.png)

Comment: You probably need to play around with css code i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the Bootstrap documentation on [Fixed to Top](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top).

> **Body padding required**
>
> The fixed navbar will overlay your other
>   content, unless you add padding to the top of the . Try out your
>   own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is
>   50px high.
>
> ```
> body { padding-top: 70px; }
> ```
>
> Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.